# Cannot Drag from Explorer onto ListView

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop

I have seen this everywhere and tried all the solutions and am not seeming to get what I want. I want to be able to drop files from explorer onto a ListView and then be able to sort them through drag and drop. I am have this simple code that gets the drag/drop from explorer.

```
        this.messageView.AllowDrop = true;
        this.messageView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 52);
        this.messageView.Name = "messageGrid";
        this.messageView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 97);
        this.messageView.TabIndex = 3;
        this.messageView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.messageView.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Form1_DragDrop);
        this.messageView.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Form1_DragEnter);
```

and the handlers

```
        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
            {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
            }
        }

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
        messageView.Items.Add(e.Data.ToString());
        }
```

This is bizarre, because of I change the messageView to a RichTextBox I have on my form, it works just fine. Are there additional steps that I have to do? When I attempt to drop onto the ListView, I get the circle with a line through it from Explorer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DragEnter and DragDrop events should be handled in the ListView, not in the Form.
About drag and drop: I do not remember the article name but I found a good example of it in codeproject.

Comment: They are handled in the listview, just the name of them is a bit funky. Do they need to be initialized somewhere other than InitializeComponent()

Comment: Change "FileGroupDescriptor" to the constant DataFormats.FileDrop, the right string should be FileDrop and in the DragDrop event you can get the right data (a string[] that you can iterate) using e.Data.GetData() method instead of ToString().